# Draw dotted polyline on Google Map - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline, dotted-line

I am working on an Android application that uses Google Maps and draws polylines on the map. I wanted to know if there is a way to draw a dotted polyline (similar to the one Google Maps shows when displaying a walking route) and how should I do that.

I have looked into the PolylineOptions object but I didn't find a method that would help me.

Is there a way do draw a dotted polyline? If so what is the method?

Thanks.

Comment: Try placing small circular marker at regular intervals .

Comment: I thought about that, but i was wondering if there was a method that could make the polyline look dotted

Comment: Take a look at my project here https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps

Comment: Thank you for the information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of February 2017, Google released a new set of customizations for polylines and polygons in Google Maps Android API v2. Now you can create dashed or dotted polylines.

See information about new features in the [Shapes Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#stroke_pattern). See an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polygon) in the Polylines and Polygons tutorial.

You can also read the corresponding blog post here:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question

Comment: Thanks Manfred, Xomena does not have enough reputation yet to mark as duplicate. What do you suggest is best in such situation?